# CSS property getting overwritten when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to insert a custom jquery slider into my html:

```
<p><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-theme="volume" />
<span style="vertical-align: top"></span>
<script>
$("[data-slider]")
  .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    $(this).nextAll("span").html(data.value.toFixed(3));
  });
</script></p>
```

This is inside a modal window. When I hardcode this into the modal window, it works fine, the styles are perfect.

However, in my javascript, when I use .append with jquery or .innerhtml on the div I am inserting it into, it shows up as just a normal textbox, no custom slider css as the hardcoded version shows.

```
                        insert_review.innerHTML += '\
                        <li class="review">\
                            <center>\
                                <p><input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-theme="volume" />\
                                <span style="vertical-align: top"></span>\
                                <script>\
                                $("[data-slider]")\
                                  .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {\
                                    $(this).nextAll("span").html(data.value.toFixed(3));\
                                  });\
                                <\/script></p>\
                            <\/center>\
                        </li>\
                        ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css classes instead of the inner HTML styling. It's better practice in the long run when you have a ton of style that you need to apply. But yeah, once you do that, just add the !important tag. This will make this property hold no matter what.

```
<style>
    .myClass{
        vertical-align: top !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I would avoid using `!important` and go for a higher specificity instead.  [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception): *Using !important is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.*

Comment: this still didn't fix my problem